# Post doctoral fellowship in France and Switzerland

Tags: postdocs

There is Humboldt experienced  Research Fellowship in Germany.
Is there any such type fellowship  in France & Switzerland?

Comment: Swiss Government Excellence Fellowships in Switzerland, in France I don't know of any specific program, though Marie Curie Fellowships allow you to choose any European destination.